# Plot3D + Graphics3D Manipulate issue

Tags: manipulate, graphics3d

I'm not sure what the issue is here.  Part of the `Plot3D` graph disappears when I use the slider.

```
Manipulate[
 Show[{
   Plot3D[x^2 + 2 y^2, {x, y} \[Element] Disk[]],
   Graphics3D[{Black, Thick, 
     Line[{{Cos[t], Sin[t], 0}, {Cos[t], Sin[t], 
        Cos[t]^2 + 2 Sin[t]^2}}]}]}, PlotRange -> 2],
 {t, 0, 2 Pi}]
```

How can I fix this?  I run across these issues from time to time when using multiple graphics with `Manipulate`.  Either it runs too slow or get some kind of behavior shown here.  Can you direct to some tips on programming `Manipulate`s?

[image]

Comment: Since you're not actually `Manipulate`ing the plot, you should generate the `Plot3D` outside of the `Manipulate` and insert it with `With`. That will fix this issue and possibly others.

Comment: Wow!  That did it.  This will definitely fix a number my issues.

Comment: add the option `PerformanceGoal -> "Quality"` to `Plot3D`?

Comment: Someone just posted an alternate answer that I thought worked well.  Any chance you could put it back up?

Comment: They used initialization at the end of Manipulate.  Is one way better than the other?

Comment: @kglr adding PerformanceGoal -> "Quality" to Plot3D does not fix it. Also PerformanceGoal -> "Speeed" does not.

Comment: @MichaelMcCain I removed my answer since I saw your answer after posting. They are the same thing. I like put stuff inside `Initialization` that is all.  When Making demos for Wolfram website, all things like this has to go to Initialization. So I am used to doing it that way.

Comment: I see.  I prefer the look of putting them inside the Manipulate as you did, but nice to know there is no difference in functionality.

Comment: @Nasser, it  "works" in version 9 (it does eliminate the jagged surface during slider movement). Of course, rendering `Plot3D` only once is better.

Answer (score 3):

Thanks to b3m2a1,

```
With[{sd = Plot3D[x^2 + 2 y^2, {x, y} \[Element] Disk[]]}, 
 Manipulate[

  Show[{
    sd,

    Graphics3D[{Black, Thick, 
      Line[{{Cos[t], Sin[t], 0}, {Cos[t], Sin[t], 
         Cos[t]^2 + 2 Sin[t]^2}}]}]}, PlotRange -> 2],

  {t, 0, 2 Pi}]]
```